# Issue with VS Community 2015 installation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to install VS Community on my PC.I'd like to make C++ applications mostly.But a problem is that it's asking whether I want **Default** or **Custom** and I'm not sure if the **Default** option contains C++ .In the **Custom** option there is a C++ ,but you have to choose it.Thanks for help!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft lists Visual C++ as a non-standard feature on their webpage so if you want to code in C++ go for the Custom

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx